# Update the MongoDB data on a socket event

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, create-react-app

I am building a messaging app using React and Node.js. Data is modelled and stored in MongoDb. I am using mongoose for db connection. I am successfully able to show the data on a api call( /getChannels).

```
app.get("/api/getChannels",cors(corsOptions), async (req,res,next) => {
    let try_channels = await Chat.find((c) => {
        return c
    });
   res.send({
       channels: try_channels
    });
})
```

But I want to update the data inside the mongoDB for a particular channel on a socket event ("channel-join") which comes from the client side when any desired channel is clicked.

```
    const handleSelect = (id) => {
        let selected_channel = channels.find((c) => {
            return c. id === id
        })
        setChannel(selected_channel)
     
        socket.emit("channel-join", id, ack => {
    });
 };
```

On the server side I am listening for the event and want to update the data inside the mongodb to show that I have joined a particular channel. I was able to do that with having an array of channels in my server.js file with the following logic

```
 socket.on('channel-join',id =>{
        console.log('channel-join',id)
        STATIC_CHANNELS.forEach(c => {
            if (c.id === id) {
                if (c.sockets.indexOf(socket.id) == (-1) ) {
                    console.log(socket.id)
                    c.sockets.push(socket.id);
                    c.participants++;
                    console.log(c.sockets,c.participants)
                    io.emit('channel' , c)
                }
            }else {
                let index = c.sockets.indexOf(socket.id);
                console.log(index)
                if (index != (-1) ) {
                    c.sockets.splice(index , 1)
                    c.participants--;
                    console.log(c.sockets,c.participants);
                    io.emit('channel',c);
                }
            }
        })
    })
```

But I am unable to get it working for data in mongodb. Should I fetch all the data first to an array and then use it ?? But that would cancel out the point of using the database in the first place wouldn't it ?
Should I do something like mongoose_model.findAndUpdate() ?? will that work ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to have a `participants` counter and increment it everytime a new client joins on the socket.

```
await db.collection('sockets').findOneAndUpdate(
  { channelId: channelId },
  { $inc: { participants: 1 } },
  { upsert: true, returnOriginal: false }
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @sks147, is there any way I can update all the other documents that do not match so that the client is connected to only one socket at any given time.